# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_IconDownloader", referenced from: & clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode4.3, iphone-5, ipad-3

Run time program  show the following error:-

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_IconDownloader", referenced from:

&

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any One solve this Problem?

Thanks In advance.

Comment: You don't say whether this is a missing symbol, a duplicate symbol, or something else.  Please include the entire error message.

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ParseOperation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_IconDownloader", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in BestSellerViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Answer (score 0):

If `ParseOperation` and `IconDownloader` are defined in source files, add those files to the compile phase for your target.  If they are defined in a library, add it to the link phase.